# How many different "shapes" can a graph have?

Tags: graph-theory

For any $n$, how many separate "shapes" of graphs using (all of and only) the numbers $1,2,..n$ as points exist such that:

Graph $a$ is the same shape as graph $b$ iff you can reorder the points in $a$ to get $b$. **Example:** any two graphs for $n=3$ that when drawn "look like triangles" are in the same group.

**Example 2:** For $n = 2$ there exist 2 shapes, (1 and 2 connected) & (1 and 2 not connected) and for $n=3$ there exist $4$: A triangle, three points  in a line, two points connected and one alone, and three alone.

Hope I've been clear enough, if not please say so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notion you're looking for (and have accurately described!) is [isomorphism of graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism).

The numbers are [here](http://oeis.org/A000088), see for instance [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86790/is-there-a-reason-why-the-number-of-non-isomorphic-graphs-with-v-4-is-odd?rq=1) for some more material. [This question on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29593/non-isomorphic-graphs-of-given-order) has even more (including pictures of all non-isomorphic graphs up to 7 nodes).

This is not my area of expertise, so I can't tell you any interesting facts, sorry!