# How to prove that if $4\mid n$ or $4\mid |n − 1$ then there is a self-complementary graph on n vertices?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I know that for a fact that with $4n$ or $4n+1$ vertices, that is definitely a self-complementary graph since a complete graph on $n$ vertices has $\frac{1}{2}\cdot n(n−1)$ edges. For a graph to be self-complementary, it must then have half that many edges, or $\frac{1}{4}\cdot n(n−1)$. For that to be an integer, $4\mid n(n−1)⟹n=4k$ or $n=4k+1$. But how does that relate to my question? Proving that if $4\mid n$ or $4\mid n-1$ then there is a self-complementary graph on $n$ vertices?

Answer (score 2):

What you have proves that if there is a self-complementary graph on $n$ vertices then either $n$ or $n-1$ is a multiple of $4$.

The converse, that if $n$ is such a number then there exists a self-complementary graph, doesn't follow, but happens to be true. The easiest way to prove it is by induction. There are self-complementary graphs with $1$ vertex (the single-vertex graph) and with $4$ vertices (the path). Now show that if you have a self-complementary graph on $n-4$ vertices, you can add four extra vertices and some edges in such a way as to ensure that the new graph is also self-complementary. (Hint: two of your new vertices should be adjacent to all the old vertices, and two to none ofthe old vertices.)

Answer (score 2):

As noted by Especially Lime you can construct self-complementary graphs recursively by adding four vertices at each iteration: [Constructing self-complementary graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40745/constructing-)

If you don't like recursive construction, the following are explicit examples.

For $n=4k$ consider the following graph:
Partition the vertices into four classes, namely $X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4$, each one containing $k$ vertices. Draw all the edges in $X_1$, all the edges in $X_2$, all the edges between $X_1$ and $X_3$, all the edges between $X_2$ and $X_4$, all the edges between $X_3$ and $X_4$.

For $n=4k+1$ pick the graph in the previous example, add a vertex $x$ and draw all the edges between $x$ and $X_1$, and all edges between $x$ and $X_2$.